# how i can put anonymous function inside normal functions argument in PHP

Tags: php

hi guys i want to put anonymous function inside normal functions argument like this:

```
public function my_function($users, function ($name) {
  echo "Hello $name";
};){

}
my_function('some_user','some_name');
```

Comment: i don,t know exact syntax any tips?:)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The body of your named function is empty. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: forgot to put code in body:D anything for example echo $users." ".$name;

Comment: give me little example how to put anonymous function inside normal functions argument :)

Comment: You cannot put a function inside a function argument definition. If you want to pass an anonymous function as argument, pass the closure when you call the function.

Comment: can you give a little example of it?

Comment: `my_function('some_user', function ($name) { echo "Hello $name"; });` `function my_function($users, $closure) { $closure($users); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you can do, is declare the anonymous function inside the body:

```
function your_function($users, $name)
{
    static $function = function($name) {
        echo "Hello $name";
    };
}
```